# use animation only once on scroll

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment below Recycler view, when scrolled down, the fragment should disappear, when scrolled up, the fragment should reappear

I implemented it but problem is, when I scroll down a little, the fragment disappearing animation takes place, when I scroll further, it reappears and the sliding down animation occurs, but I want it to remain hidden untill the next scroll up.

Here is my code:

```
 mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                Log.d("newstate",newState+"");


            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
               Log.d("dx",dx+"");
                Log.d("dy",dy+"");

                FragmentTransaction ft1 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft1.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.entry, R.anim.exit);
                ft1.show(bmfragment);
                ft1.commit();
                    visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
                    totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();


                if(dy<0) {

                        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.entry, R.anim.exit);
                        ft.show(bmfragment);
                        ft.commit();


                }else if(firstVisibleItem>=1)
                {

                        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                        ft.setCustomAnimations(0, R.anim.exit);
                        ft.hide(bmfragment);
                        ft.commit();


                }




            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! I just used a flag variable

```
@Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
               Log.d("dx",dx+"");
                Log.d("dy",dy+"");

                if(flag==false) {
                    FragmentTransaction ft1 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft1.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.entry, R.anim.exit);
                    ft1.show(bmfragment);
                    ft1.commit();
                    visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
                    totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                }


                if(dy<0) {

                        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.entry, R.anim.exit);
                        ft.show(bmfragment);
                        ft.commit();
                        flag = false;

                }else if(firstVisibleItem>=1)
                {
                    if(flag==false) {

                        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                        ft.setCustomAnimations(0, R.anim.exit);
                        ft.hide(bmfragment);
                        ft.commit();
                        flag=true;
                    }


                }
                Log.d("visibleItemCount",visibleItemCount+"");
                Log.d("firstVisibleItem",firstVisibleItem+"");




            }
        });
```